# LinkedIn API - Organization Brand Time-Bound Returns Only Time Range

Tags: python, linkedin-api

My goal here is to retrieve page views for my LinkedIn brand page by day. However, the response i receive from LinkedIn when using the appropriate GET URL contains the given time range but does not contain any brand page statistics. Is there something that i'm missing in order to retrieve brand page time-bound statistics?

Below is the GET URL and the response.

GET URL:
"https://api.linkedin.com/v2/brandPageStatistics?q=brand&brand=urn:li:organizationBrand[mycompanybrand]&timeIntervals.timeGranularityType=DAY&timeIntervals.timeRange.start=1596153600000&timeIntervals.timeRange.end=1596265199999"

Response:

```
{

    "paging": {
        "start": 0,
        "count": 10,
        "links": []
    },
    "elements": [
        {
            "brand": "urn:li:organizationBrand:[mycompanybrand]",
            "timeRange": {
                "start": 1596153600000,
                "end": 1596240000000
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The brand page averages over 1000 page views a month. I've run this request with a larger time range with confirmed page views within the given range but receive the same result. Continually, using the non-time-bound GET URL returns a plethora of data.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I don't understand it either

Comment: If you follow the same process to retrieve organization data but substitute the Organization ID with the Brand ID then it works. ie "urn:li:organization:[BrandID]"